# Kernel/Firmware as Debian package

Tags: debian, kernel, apt

It says on the [official site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md) that "the kernel and firmware are installed as a Debian package, and so will also get updates when using [apt-get upgrade]"

I `run apt-get update` / `apt-get dist-upgrade` relatively frequently, yet when I run `uname -a` I get the following result:

```
Linux rpi 3.12.28+ #709 PREEMPT Mon Sep 8 15:28:00 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Since I am using a [reduced version of Debian](http://lessbian.org/), is there any specific package I need to install or something I have to do in order to tie the firmware into the `apt` packages?

I'd prefer not to have to run `rpi-update` often, as that provides bleeding-edge versions of kernel, something I'd rather not have.

Comment: Note that the foundation's page is about [Updating and Upgrading *Raspbian*](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md "Updating and Upgrading Raspbian") (emphasis mine). If you're running a custom, cut-down, systemd-excised Debian system, you won't get the Raspbian-specific updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and you're good to go. Once done, reboot. It should be upgraded to 3.18.xx kernel. You can verify it by `uname -a` after rebooting.

While as per Deviantfan's comment,

> A normal upgrade refuses to add or remove packets, and if this is
>   necessary for upgrading existing ones (new dependencies etc.), these
>   packets won´t upgrade. Dist-upgrade includes adding/removing
>   dependencies if necessary. That´s all

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did not work. Same version as before. For reference, the list of packages upgraded was `binutils libgnutls-deb0-28 libgnutls-openssl27 libpsl0 libsystemd0 libterm-readkey-perl libudev1 udev`
If it makes a difference, `sources` is set to stretch and I'm running the system off a flash drive (the SD card is just boot).

Comment: `dist-upgrade is totally different thing` Eh no. A normal upgrade refuses to add or remove packets, and if this is necessary for upgrading existing ones (new dependencies etc.), these packets won´t upgrade. Dist-upgrade includes adding/removing dependencies if necessary. That´s all.

Comment: @deviantfan You're right. My bad. Edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

`dist-upgrade` by itself will not upgrade you to a new OS release unless you modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` beforehand and point `apt` the the repositories of the OS release that you want to get.

More precisely, `dist-upgrade` merely specifies a conflict resolution mechanism that is less conservative that the one used by regular `upgrade`. `dist-upgrade` allows `apt` to remove some previously installed packages if these packages create dependency chains that make the entire upgrade impossible.